# Filtering object from an array by checking a matched value in a map (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a `data` and a `map`.

```
let data = [
    { 
        'name': 'bob',
        'items': ['111']
    },
    { 
        'name': 'Jane',
        'items': ['111']
    },
    { 
        'name': 'Greg',
        'items': ['222']
    }
]

let item_map = [
    { 'Item1': '111', 'Item2': '222'}
]
```

The `items` in `data` object contains the `ids` of the `item`.
What I am trying to do is to filter out the object from `data` where using a list of values matched to the `id` of the map.

For example, given ['Item1'], I want to get

```
[{ 
        'name': 'bob',
        'items': ['111']
    },
    { 
        'name': 'Jane',
        'items': ['111']
}]
```

What I tried is

```
data.filter( item => ['111'].some(filter => (item_map["Item1"]).includes(filter)))
```

But this keeps giving me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined` error.

**EDIT**

```
data.filter(item => ['111'].some(filter => item_map[0]["Item1"].includes(filter)))
```

This is what I newly tried, but this just returns all three items.

Comment: `item_map` does not have an "Item1" property. It is an array, and its element is an object with that property.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that and I am still getting a wrong output. It gives me something though. Any help?

Comment: Maybe remove that first attempt from your question, since it is ... no longer your question.

Comment: Wait so is the item_map what you want your output to look like?

Comment: What you did does not make sense: you take a literal array with one literal string "111", and then check that "Item1" (which is "111") includes "111". This is obviously true, no matter how many times you iterate over `data`. You don't actually use the `item` you get from `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't exactly understand why you'd choose an array for an items "map", but to conform with your current data structure, this is the correct logic:

```js
let filters = ['Item1'];
data.filter((datum) => {
    return filters.some((filter) => datum.items.includes(item_map[0][filter]));
});
```